# FLS in SOQL - VisualForce vs LWC

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, soql, fls

I have a VF page and an LWC, both the UI are displaying a datatable of records `Project__c`.

User A (Standard user) doesn't have access to `Report__c` and `Geographic__c` field on Project__c.

The VF page shows the column header but doesn't retrieve the field value:
[image]

The LWC is on the other hand doesn't follow the same settings:
[image]

Note: The SOQL queries are the same for both the UIs.

Is this how it works in LWC?

Comment: Show us your LWC code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The experience you get with LWC entirely depends on whether you use standard components or your own code.

In Visualforce you get FLS automatically applied when you use the `apex:outputField` or `apex:inputField` for example, and you will get the same sort of result when using the `uiRecordApi` within LWC, where FLS is automatically applied.

On the other hand, if you are simply calling an aura enabled method to get data for populating your display in LWC where this method simply performs an SOQL query to get the data to be displayed, then render the results (e.g. in a datatable) this is akin to using `apex:outputText` - there are no built-in FLS checks without you doing them for yourself.

To apply FLS you have a bunch of different options, such as [Security.stripInaccessible](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_with_security_stripInaccessible.htm) or SOQL's [WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_with_security_enforced.htm), though the approach applied depends on your requirements and required UX.

Basically, if you roll your own logic and rendering, it is up to you as a developer to consider CRUD and FLS (plus sharing if required).

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: No official documentation as such, but an [internet search](https://www.ecosia.org/search?p=1&q=crud+fls+in+lwc+salesforce) will find many results that tell you much the same thing.